# How to remove all ACC/BIM360 users who are not in the manage portal?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Can I use APS/Forge to remove all users from ACC/BIM360 who are not in the Manage portal? More generally, is there a way I can use APS/Forge to keep both lists in sync?

I looked through the public API pages, compiled a list of users that are different using the UI functionality, but have found no way besides clicking through the UI 1-by-1 to remove each individual. A way to bulk remove would save a great deal of time (if it exists).

Comment: I am not familiar with Manage Portal you mentioned, but are you trying to remove the user from ACC/BIM360 Account? or remove them from ACC/BIM360 Project?

Comment: I am trying to remove them from the ACC/BIM 360 account. The manage portal I am refering to is here: https://manage.autodesk.com/home/, and contains users connected to current billing iirc. The intent is to remove 'non-current' users from ACC/BIM360.